# How to select the field's increment from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table recording the accumulative total visit numbers of some web pages every day. I want to fetch the real visit numbers in a specific day for all these pages. the table is like

```
- record_id   page_id     date     addup_number
 - 1             1        2012-9-20     2110
 - 2             2        2012-9-20     1160
 - ...          ...          ...         ...
 - n             1        2012-9-21     2543
 - n+1           2        2012-9-21     1784
```

the result I'd like to fetch is like:

```
 - page_id      date        increment_num(the real visit numbers on this date)
 - 1           2012-9-21      X
 - 2           2012-9-21      X
 - ...           ...         ...
 - N           2012-9-21      X
```

but I don't want to do this in php, cause it's time consuming. Can I get what I want with SQL directives or with some mysql functions?

Comment: poorly stated question.  consider clarifying what you really are trying to ask with more illustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. You need to join the table on itself by joining on the `date` column and adding a day to one side of the join.

Assuming:

1. `date` column is a legitimate `DATE` Type and not a string
2. Every day is accounted for each page (no gaps)
3. addup_number is an `INT` of some type (`BIGINT`, `INT`, `SMALLINT`, etc...)
4. table_name is substituted for your actual table name which you don't indicate
5. Only one record per day for each page... i.e. no pages have multiple counts on the same day

You can do this:

```
SELECT t2.page_id, t2.date, t2.addup_number - t1.addup_number AS  increment_num
  FROM table_name t1
  JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY = t2.date
  WHERE  t1.page_id = t2.page_id
```

One thing to note is if this is a huge table and `date` is an indexed column, you'll suffer on the join by having to transform it by adding a day in the `ON` clause, but you'll get your data.

Comment: May be I should blame myself for my poor English?? Why you guys always tell me to sum the addup_number? haa..., I explained above, excuse me for copying and pasting here:.I want the increment number, e.g I have 2100 visits at 2012-9-21, and 2600 at 2012-9-22, I want 2600-2100=500 returned, and I want this for every page(1-N, about 100 pages or more)

Comment: @zoujyjs ah, much more challenging

Comment: @zoujyjs  see the answer above, it should get you exactly what you want

Comment: Amazing! your Assuming is exactly the truth that I did. And I get the right result! Thanks! JOIN is a sort of advanced feature that I have never used before !

Comment: @zoujyjs if it worked, great.  Please vote up my answer and make it correct if it addressed your need.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

```
SELECT today.page_id, today.date, (today.addup_number - yesterday.addup_number) as increment
 FROM myvisits_table today, myvisits_table yesterday
WHERE today.page_id = yesterday.page_id
    AND today.date='2012-9-21'
    AND yesterday.date='2012-9-20'
GROUP BY today.page_id, today.date, yesterday.page_id, yesterday.date
ORDER BY page_id
```

Comment: I am not fiding the hotest webpage every day, you mistook my questions...I want the increment number, e.g I have 2100 visits at 2012-9-21, and 2600 at 2012-9-22, I want 2600-2100=500 returned, and I want this for every page(1-N, about 100 pages or more)

Comment: @zoujyjs I have updated my answer, now that I understand better your need. I cannot guarantee it's error-freee (I don't have an SQL shell right now) but maybe it will show you the right direction.

Comment: thks a lot, I will try this tomorrow~ be home mow~ I will tell you the result!

Comment: @zoujyjs  So, what's the result? Did you manage to get it working? Was I 'far from the truth'?

Comment: that works well, it get the real visit numbers in a specific date. The answer above is more general since it gives the result of all date! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT date, SUM(addup_number) 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: you mistook my question, I want the increment number, e.g I have 2100 visits at 2012-9-21, and 2600 at 2012-9-22, I want 2600-2100=500 returned, and for every page(1-N, about 100 pages or more). You return the total number of all pages on different days